# Advise on summing up values in a list

Tags: java, list, sum, compare

I have a list of strings like below:

```
"AB", "XY", 10
"CD", "XY", 15
"CD", "XY", 12
"AB", "XY", 19
```

What I want to do is to sum up the numbers in the last value for the first values and to put that in a new list.

So that would give me:

```
"AB", "XY", 29
"CD", "XY", 27
```

I'm new to Java so I'm still struggling with the syntax and different methods. I looked in to the compareTo() and the equals() method but alas. Could use some help.

Comment: If you're on Java 8, you could use streams and `groupingBy`, e.g. see http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/java-util-stream-groupingBy-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is: why do you have that as a list of String? It appears that you have instead a list of an object that contains 3 properties: 2 Strings and an integer. Having such a data structure would make the code a lot easier to read and write.

Now, to solve that problem, you first need to make a map that will hold the first part of the String and the sum of the numbers:

1. Using the Stream API, the map is created by using the `Collectors.groupingBy` collector that will classify each String into the first part of the String, i.e. everything before the last comma. Then, for all the values classified to the same key, we sum, using `Collectors.summingInt`, the number that is after the last comma.
2. When we have that map, we can then iterate over all its entries and convert each entry back into a `String` and finally collect that into a list with `Collectors.toList()`.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("\"AB\", \"XY\", 10", "\"CD\", \"XY\", 15", "\"CD\", \"XY\", 12", "\"AB\", \"XY\", 19");

    Map<String, Integer> map =
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                s -> s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(',')),
                Collectors.summingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(',') + 2)))
            ));
    List<String> result =
        map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .map(e -> e.getKey() + ", " + e.getValue())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked partially. I'm reading into the API you mentioned now. I'm a bit closer but I think its taking the first and second value as a key now and sums up the values for those. How would I use this method to completely ignore the second value and only take the first as a key and sum up everything for the first string value?


So it would look like:
"AB",  29

"CD", 27

Edit: nevermind figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

input data:

```
"AB", "XY", 10
"CD", "XY", 15
"CD", "XY", 12
"AB", "XY", 19
"AB", "XY", 3
```

code:

```
String inputData = "\"AB\", \"XY\", 10\n\"CD\", \"XY\", 15\n\"CD\", \"XY\", 12\n\"AB\", \"XY\", 19\n\"AB\", \"XY\", 3";

final String[] lines = inputData.split("\\n");

Map<String,Integer> results = new HashMap<>();

final Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile("([\\\"A-Z,\\s]+),\\s(\\d+)");

for (String line : lines) {
    final Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(line);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        final String groupName = matcher.group(1);
        final int value = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));

        if (results.containsKey(groupName)) {
            final Integer currentValue = results.get(groupName);

            results.put(groupName, (currentValue+value));
    } else {
        results.put(groupName, value);
    }
}
```

output for my data:

```
"CD", "XY" > 27
"AB", "XY" > 32
```